# Eee PC 1215P display issue

Tags: crash, vga, eee-pc

Randomly, my Eee PC 1215P will crash while booting or running windows like this video below.

[video](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6882637/ASUS%20Eee%20PC%201215P%20LCD%20Issue.mp4)
Any advice?